# Get the Video still URL of a brightcove video in a js variable

Tags: javascript, video, brightcove

When using Brightcove videos as an HTML object I need to get the URL of the image still into the `stillUrl` variable. I tried looking through the Brightcove documentation but there's much too much information to filter out. How do I make the API call?

```
onTemplateLoad = function(experienceID){
    player = brightcove.api.getExperience(experienceID);
    modVP = player.getModule(brightcove.api.modules.APIModules.VIDEO_PLAYER);
    stillUrl = "?????";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't try to get the video still in the *template loaded* event listener. This is executed when the player loads, before the video is loaded into the player. There is a method to get the video data which you can use in a *template ready* event listener — `modVP.getCurrentVideo(function(video){stillURL = video.videoStillURL})` — but I generally prefer adding an event listener for the Media Change event:

```
onTemplateLoad = function(experienceID){
  player = brightcove.api.getExperience(experienceID);
  modVP = player.getModule(brightcove.api.modules.APIModules.VIDEO_PLAYER);
  modVP.addEventListener(brightcove.api.events.MediaEvent.CHANGE, onChange);
}
```

and get the video still from the event passed to that function:

```
onChange = function(event){
  stillUrl = event.media.videoStillURL;
}
```